# Navegación en PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces

estoy progamando en PrimeFaces. Quiero crear un botón nuevo que me navegue al otra pantalla. He añadido el nuevo método al xml de navegación, si embargo no pasa de pantalla aunque si entra dentro del método.
Os dejo el código por aquí.
Primero va la página JSP. El archivo JAVA y tras esto el XML de navegación.
Gracias

````
<ui:imageHyperlink id="detalle"  imageURL="/images/detail.gif"  rendered="#{pages$PeriodicOperations.roleConfiguracio}"
                                                action="#{pages$PeriodicOperations.duplicarOperation}"  toolTip="#{text['periodicOperations.detalle']}"
                                                onClick="doOther(#{currentRow.value['registerId']}, #{currentRow.value['periodicOperationId']});" />            ```
````

```
public String duplicarOperation() {
    log.info("Entrando en duplicarOperation");
    PeriodicOperation po = periodicOperationManager.getPeriodicOperation(new Long((String)opeId.getValue()));
    //po.setPeriodicOperationId(null);
    sessionBean.setPeriodicOperation(po);
    log.info("Saliendo de duplicarOperation");
    return "duplicarcioOperation";
    
}
```

```
<navigation-case><from-outcome>duplicarOperation   </from-outcome><to-view-id>/pages/PeriodicOperationManagement.jsp    </to-view-id>           </navigation-case>
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema estaba en el return del método que no estaba bien escrito.

```
public String duplicarOperation() {
    log.info("Entrando en duplicarOperation");
    PeriodicOperation po = periodicOperationManager.getPeriodicOperation(new Long((String)opeId.getValue()));
    //po.setPeriodicOperationId(null);
    sessionBean.setPeriodicOperation(po);
    log.info("Saliendo de duplicarOperation");
    return "duplicarOperation";
    
}
```

De esta manera si es correcto.